# HTML/CSS: How to show a background picture that has 100% width and 100% height below a header

Tags: html, css, background, height, width

I am trying to put a background picture below the header. The picture is supposed to cover all the width and height, but should not cover the header. However, the background picture does not show up. What’s wrong in my code?? Thank you for taking your time My codes are below;

Part of my `html` is below;

```
<body>

<header>
  <p class="btn1"><img src="images/thumb2.jpg" class="skypic" alt="skypic"><span class="stext">picA</span></p>
  <p class="btn2"><span class="king"><img src="images/king.png"></span><a href="xxx.php"><img src="images/B.jpg"></a></p>
</header>

<div id="wrapper" class="stampwrap">

</div>
</body>
```

and part of my `css` is below;

```
body{
  font: 14px/1.6 sans-serif;
  color:#313131;
  background: #67b2e4;
}

header{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 80px;
  background: #67b2e4;
  padding: 2% 4%;
}

.btn1{
  float:left;
}

.btn1 .stext {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 20px;
  float:right;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.btn2{
  float: right;
}

.skypic{
  height: 80px;
  width: auto;
}

#wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  width:100%;
  background: url(images/zzz.jpg);
}

.stampwrap{
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the height of the `body` element. the `wrapper` class has no space to be viewed. `height:100%;` cannot be seen in a parent `body` element with `height:0px;` which is the default if not defined.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I added `height: 100%;` on the body element, but it still does not work well, could you possibly guess why?

Comment: Try nesting in `<div>` instead of `<p>`. `<p>` elements were intended for text, not images. And i'm not 100% sure if an `<a>` can call a `.php` file.